# AKplayer and AKAudioPlayer plug headphones will silence on iPhone6s iPhone8s

Tags: audiokit

AKplayer and AKAudioPlayer  plug headphones are silent on iPhone6s iPhone8s AKplayer is still playing.
I've tried in many ways, all without success

This my code:

```
do {

    AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true;
    try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playback, with: .mixWithOthers)

    let backFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp3")!
    let backUrl = URL.init(string: backFile)!
    backPlayer = AKPlayer.init(url: backUrl)
    AudioKit.output = backPlayer
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        print("AudioKit.start()失败")
    }

} catch {
    AKLog("Could not set session category.")
}
```